# how do i pass an aditional text to a request from the frontend to the backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, openapi

So in here, I am trying to make an additional text that gets sent to the backend along with the user input, but for some reason, I keep getting random texts as a response. I have different tools and one code for the request, here I am trying to send with each tool that is being used, two data one is an additional text that describes the prompt and the user input.

```
const ProductDescription = () => {
  const additionaltext = 'create a product description for the following product';
  const handleCopyText = () => {
    copyText(response);
  };
  
  const handleShare = () => {
    shareTagline(response);
  };
  
  const handleExport = () => {
    exportTagline(response);
  };

  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState('');
  const [response, setResponse] = useState('');

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setUserInput(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleButtonClick = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/generate', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ additionaltext, userInput }),
});
      const data = await response.json();
      setResponse(data.generatedText);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>
        <Container>
          <br />
          <br />
          <Typography variant="h4">Generate Compelling Product Descriptions with AI</Typography>
          <br />
          <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
          Enhance your product listings with engaging descriptions.
          </Typography>
          <br />
          <br />
          <form id="my-form" >
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <FormControl variant="standard" sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
                  <InputLabel shrink htmlFor="bootstrap-input">
                  What product would you like to generate a description for?
          </InputLabel>
                  
                  <BootstrapInput fullWidth value={userInput} onChange={handleInputChange}/>
                </FormControl>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item align="left" xs={3}>
                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" fullWidth onClick={handleButtonClick}>
                  Get AI Suggestions
                </Button>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </form>

          <br />
          <br />
          <Card>
            <CardHeader
              title="The AI reponse will be shown here"
              action={
                <>
                  <IconButton aria-label="Menu" onClick={handleClick}>
                    <MoreVertIcon />
                  </IconButton>
                  <StyledMenu
                    MenuListProps={{
                      "aria-labelledby": "",
                    }}
                    anchorEl={anchorEl}
                    open={open}
                    onClose={handleClose}
                  >
                    <MenuItem onClick={() => { handleShare(); handleClose(); }} disableRipple>
                      <Share />
                      Share
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem onClick={() => { handleCopyText(); handleClose(); }}  disableRipple>
                      <Copy />
                      Copy
                    </MenuItem>
                    <Divider sx={{ my: 0.5 }} />
                    <MenuItem onClick={() => { handleExport(); handleClose(); }} disableRipple>
                      <Export />
                      Export
                    </MenuItem>
                  </StyledMenu>
                </>
              }
            >
             
            </CardHeader>
            <Divider />
            <br />
            <CardContent>
              <Typography variant="h6">{response}</Typography>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Container>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};
export default ProductDescription;
```

and here is the API call :

```
    const axios = require('axios');
async function generateProductDescription(additionaltext, userInput) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      'https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/text-davinci-001/completions',
      {
        prompt: `${additionaltext} ${userInput}`,
        max_tokens: 100,
        temperature: 0.8,
        top_p: 1,
        frequency_penalty: 0,
        presence_penalty: 0,
        stop: ['"""'],
      },
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: 'Bearer OPEN-APIKEY',
        },
      }
    );

    const generatedText = response.data.choices[0].text;
    return generatedText;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    throw new Error('Something went wrong');
  }
}

module.exports = { generateProductDescription };
```

Comment: What "*random texts*" are you getting?

Comment: @Aleksandar , when i write this in the additional text : generate a testimonial for the following product, and the user input for example can be this : Email inbox cleaner, the response should be something about it but I get this for example: The Inbox Cleaner plugin is a discontinued plugin that is no longer available for download.